# How to get all the nodes under a folder using extjs in CQ5?

Tags: extjs, aem

I'm trying to avoid duplicate title (jcr:title) under particular folder from UI.  Is there any CQ.Ext js get method to fetch all the nodes under a folder and loop through each node's jcr:title?

CQ.utils.HTTP.get(parentPath + "/jcr:content/jcr:title");

this will get the title of one particular node only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.2.` selector to get a page node with all its children and the children `jcr:content` nodes. Iterate the response JSON to get `jcr:title` property for each page.

Following code uses jQuery [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to avoid creating an extra array:

```
$CQ.map(CQ.Util.eval('/content/geometrixx/en.2.json'), function(v) {
  if (typeof v['jcr:content'] != 'undefined') {
    return v['jcr:content']['jcr:title'];
  }
});

>> ["Toolbar", "Products", "Services", "Company", "Events", "Support", "Community", "GeoBlog"]
```

Comment: To get all nodes under a folder wouldn't you want to use .inifinity. instead of .2.?

Comment: `.infinity.` would give you all children, and children's children, etc., basically a whole subtree. On the other hand, `.2.` returns a subtree with height 2. In other words, the selector defines a height of the subtree rather than number of nodes.